# Auto-refresh echo

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a code:

```
<span id="refresh"><?echo $users;?></span>
```

Here appear total users registered and I want to auto refresh this, for example if appear 100, when somebody has registered to my site, I want to auto update this number from 100 to 101 without refreshing page.

Comment: You should at least attempt that ajax portion.

Comment: You've provided a description of your program. You have not provided a question for anyone to answer.

Comment: @DanGrossman: he did. I want to auto update this number from 100 to 101 without refreshing page.

Comment: Dan Grossman, my question is "how to make auto refresh". If I don't provide a description, how you will know to answer for my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A php varible is only rendered to the screen as the page is being preprocessed. Rather than have the echo there you'll want to use AJAX to fetch the user count.

```
$.ajax({
     type : 'GET',
     url : 'user_count.php',
     success : function(data){

          $('#refresh').html(data);
     },
});
```

The example above is using jQuery's ajax method. You could call this in a timer and echo out the user count in user_count.php. This would then set the contents of refresh with the count gathered from the AJAX request.

Hope this made sense and helped you.

Tim

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){
    setInterval(function(){ 
         $("#refresh").load("registered_users_count.php");
    }, 10000);
});
```

Comment: Where does it say the OP is using jQuery?

Comment: This is what the OP would need to do. Possibly not jquery, but this is still a valid answer. The answer just needs some explanation as to what this code actually does. Rather than just dropping it here, otherwise how will the OP know what it all means.

Answer (score 1):

An Ajax call is the better way to go but as a quick easy alternative you can have a simple php file like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo $users; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

and have it in a small `<iframe>` in your main page.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want to use iframe.