# How do I pass value of ajax variable to php script in this example?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Notice this post:

[Auto-refresh echo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882365/auto-refresh-echo)

One solution was to do this:

down vote

```
$(function(){
    setInterval(function(){ 
         $("#refresh").load("user_count.php");
    }, 10000);
});
```

All this does is it talks to user_count.php to GET data.  The .php file then sends that back to be printed out on the page.  But say I wanted to also send data to the .php file for it to do stuff with.  So like I defined two variables in the javascript code, then wanted the value of each variable to be sent to that php script for processing.  What's the syntax for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it to the URL:

```
$("#refresh").load("user_count.php?something="+valueA+"&somethingElse="+valueB);
```

BTW - these are JavaScript variables, not "AJAX variables".

Comment: ah how elegant!  I'll give that a try.

Comment: that worked, although I bung my head a few times until figured out I forgot the jquery script include in the head section.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .ajax(): http://jqapi.com/#p=jQuery.ajax

```
$.ajax({
  url: "mypage.php",
  data: {
     foo: 1,
     bar: "blah"
  },
  context: document.body,
  success: function(ret){
    alert("Anything your php script outputs will be returned to the ret variable");
    alert(ret);
  }
});
```

You php file will then be able to use `$_POST['foo']` and `$_POST['bar']`.

Answer (score 0):

A really simple solution to this would be to use `$.param()` and append it onto your URL:

```
$(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $('#refresh').load('user_count.php?'+ $.param({
            yourFirstVariable: 'foo', 
            anotherVariable: 'bar'
        }));
    }, 10000);
});
```

Where `yourFirstVariable` and `anotherVariable` are parameters for your php script.